# Xcode add libraries to the library browser

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I don't know how to ask for it, but whenever I type xcode and library in google, it shows me "how to link to a library with xcode".

My question is how do I add the libraries from /usr/local/lib (or custom ones) to the default proposed libraries or frameworks when I go to "build phase" and the + of "link binary with libraries" ?

I tried first to add the library or frameworks search path, but seems not to affect the default proposed libraries and frameworks. The default ones I have are in two folders "OSX 10.11" and "Developper Frameworks".

I know i can add other and then cmd+maj+G to my /usr/local/lib, or even drag and drop the libraries but it means i have to go the correct path which is pretty the same steps. Then I think it is a waste of time when the major part of the libraries I use is located into /usr/local/lib.

I didn't find any options in the xcode settings ? Is there any way to do that ? maybe an xcode plugin ?

Comment: I don't think you can add custom libraries.

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe i fear you're right. Maybe an xcode plugin/package ? I installed a few plugins so i imagine it could be hack by anyway ?

Comment: I cannot say (I don't know), but I doubt it.

Comment: I found this [link](http://superuser.com/questions/894958/mac-os-x-xcode-libraries). I managed to do the first way. But not to create my own sdk directory, maybe i didn't put the right things in the ".pkist" file. I know I should comment the answer but i don't have enough reputation ^^ ...